# How to implement a range of integers with enum like accessibility?

Tags: java, groovy, enums, integer

So currently I'm working with an enum called `OneToSeven`, which as the name suggests enumerates numbers one to seven, for example

```java
OneToSeven someRankingValue;
```

and it would be used like

```java
someRankingValue.id = OneToSeven.ONE
```

and

```java
someRankingValue.displayName = OneToSeven.ONE.displayName
```

inside the OneToSeven enum I've got

```java
enum OneToSeven implements ReferenceData {
    ONE("1", "1"),
    TWO("2", "2"),
    THREE("3", "3"),
    FOUR("4", "4"),
    FIVE("5", "5"),
    SIX("6", "6"),
    SEVEN("7", "7")
    
    private String id
    private String displayName

    private OneToSeven(String id, String displayName) {
        this.id = id
        this.displayName = displayName
    }

    @Override
    String getId() {
        id
    }

    @Override
    String getDisplayName() {
        displayName
    }
}
```

I'm currently stuck trying to figure out a better implementation (doesn't have to be with enums) that would be flexible enough to cater for other ranges (1-3, or 0-6) that can be 'configured' based on requirements. Ideally I want to avoid having `OneToSeven`, `OneToThree`, `ZeroToFive` enums. Also having trouble describing what kind of development problem this would fall under.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Enums are static by nature, so there won't be any configuration you can do. Why not just a `Range` class that accepts two integers?

Comment: `someRankingValue.id = OneToSeven.ONE.id` this is wrong.  `OneToSeven.ONE` is an immutable singleton instance so it should be `someRankingValue = OneToSeven.ONE`.  You can't configure the members of an enum at runtime.  You'll need to define your own class for that.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Thanks Chris, I don't think I could use Range as I would still need to implement the ReferenceData class that provides the ability to interact with `someRankingValue` via `id` or `displayName`. Although perhaps there isn't such a way given the static aspect of enums. I am considering some sort of use of Range with ReferenceData though. Thank you.

Comment: @JimGarrison, ah yep typo, i'll fix that up. Thanks.

Comment: So your comments reveal that the real issue is about implementing this `ReferenceData` interface. Perhaps you should show us that interface.

Comment: Are your ranges always numeric? Always contiguous?

Comment: What about EnumSet.of(...

Comment: what is the use-case?

Comment: You can think of annotations as well but again it depends on the use-case.

Comment: Guava or Apache has Range type which will probably be better solution for whatever problem you have.